# How to parse cyrillic chars in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fetching and storing rss feeds with cyrillic chars in them. But Ruby does not parse those and instead the output looks like this

```
[34] pry(main)> f.title
=> 
"???? ????? ??? ?????? ?? ??????? ? ???????????????????????????????????"
```

How are you supposed to parse chars like that?

I use feed-normalizer to parse rss

```
feed = FeedNormalizer::FeedNormalizer.parse open("http://fokus.mk/feed/atom/")
```

Comment: Sharing `url` or, at least, the real file content / encoding could help us to answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa http://fokus.mk/feed/atom/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]" and "[ask]". We need to see the minimal necessary supporting data (HTML) IN the question itself, not as a link. Links break, making your question make no sense to people searching for similar solutions in the future.

Comment: The problem isn't Ruby, at least not current Rubies as I can open the URL using RestClient and from inside IRb using OpenURI and see the Cyrillic characters correctly. What version of Ruby are you using? What encoding is your terminal set to? What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-linux]. Running a vagrant box on a ubuntu/trusty64 .My terminal encoding is en_US.UTF-8, thanks @theTinMan

Comment: Please put that information *in the question itself* not in comments. Putting information necessary for answering the question in comments forces potential answerers to read every comment and try to piece it all together.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'net/http'

feed = FeedNormalizer::FeedNormalizer.parse(
  File.read(open("http://fokus.mk/feed/atom/")).force_encoding('UTF-8')
)
```

or:

```
feed = FeedNormalizer::FeedNormalizer.parse(
  Net::HTTP.get('fokus.mk', '/feed/atom/').force_encoding('UTF-8')
)
```

Comment: Did you try this? I'm getting NoMethodError: undefined method `force_encoding' for #<Tempfile:/tmp/open-uri201
51229-2706-9fbmfq> with the first solution and the 2nd solution gives me the same result: ?????????? ??????? ????? ?? ??????

Comment: I have tried the second one; first one depends on where monkeypatched `open` came from. BTW, what version of ruby do you use? I have the first variant updated to conform your `open`.

Comment: I use ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-linux]. I also tried the updated solution1 which works but still returns "?????" :/

Comment: This sounds weird to me. I would blame `FeedNormalizer`. Would you mind to try http://feedjira.com/ ? I just can’t realize why the code above works for me and does not for you.

Comment: I just used feedjira and still returns the same thing. I use vagrant to run trusty64, if that helps. I have no idea whats going

Comment: Alright, i managed to get this working in the console when I ran through PowerShell instead of the cmd.

Comment: when you are prying enter `RUBY_VERSION` and show result